# canMoveRowAtIndexPath doesn't get called - but canEditRowAtIndexPath does

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Very very basic. I don't understand. When the table loads and when Edit is toggled `canEdit` is called, but not `canMove`. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSLog(@"canEdit=%d", indexPath.row);  
  // output is as expected, "canEdit" for each row
  return (indexPath.section == 1) ? YES : NO;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSLog(@"canMove=%d", indexPath.row);
  // nothing. No output
  return (indexPath.section == 1) ? YES : NO;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How many total sections are in your table?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry, the issue is answered here:

[Reorder control isn't displayed on table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769418/reorder-control-isnt-displayed-on-table-view)

You have to also implement

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
```

**Swift**:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: This should be 

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath

Comment: I have both of the Swift methods implemented and canMoveRowAt prints a message for each possible execution path.  When editing mode is entered, all the cells are referenced and a message is printed for each, but after performing a move and then scrolling the view up/down to refresh it, the debug output shows that only some cells, not all, are iterated through.